# target for number between two different special characters

Tags: replace

I have the following string, where I want to change the number `"merged_boris_20220712.boris"`. If instead of underscores it had dashes, I would just go to the numbers and do `ciw` and type the new number, but underscore are part of `word` so this doesn't work here. What would be an efficient solution here?

Comment: Probably `f2ct.` or `f2cw` should work (the latter assuming `.` is not in `iskeyword`). Do either work for you? Depending on the edit, C-x/C-a are options

Comment: I actually used the latter and made a mental note to not rely on `i`something so much :)

Comment: I have been using [this since forever](https://github.com/3N4N/dotFiles/blob/6ee18e8855097b21b24ca73b4b44114b4621bb7a/.config/nvim/init.vim#L271-L276). See if it helps.

Comment: Oh you wanted to change between `_` and `.`. I misunderstood. Never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of `f2ct.` or `f2cw` should work (the latter assuming `.` is not in `iskeyword`). Depending on the edit, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> are also options.

Another: `/\d\+`<kbd>Enter</kbd>`cgn`. There is no binding for `cd`, so you could do

```
:nnoremap cd /\d\+<enter>cgn
```

to make `cd` change the next (whole) number.

Comment: thanks, also learned about `gn` today